# 3.3v Relay switches on/off/on - off fails 2nd switch off

Tags: gpio, python, relay

This 3.3v .[relay](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001152415492.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dLKHzIS), link to the the >>> [Datasheet](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/157071/DBLECTRO/JQC-3FC/384/1/JQC-3FC.html)

As the title mentions works fine until I try to switch it off the second time round,
I see the red LED turning on (it looks a touch dim)

*Tapping the relay housing(lightly) triggers the relay
**Stuck relay then**!*

**But why only after the second attempt and never on the first power off ?**

*EDIT: I looked at the datasheet thinking it needs a bit more voltage, but max is 3.9v!*

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
#from time import sleep
pin =2
# Set up input pin
# set bcm pin mode 
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
#  turn on relay in revese mode so sety pin to low
state = GPIO.input(pin)
if state:
 print('on')
 GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW) 
else:
 print('off')
 GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Comment: Try a different GPIO.  GPIO 2 and 3 have hard-wired pull-ups to   3V3.

Comment: @joan, good idea I shall try that in a mo n reply back

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. "Set up input pin…GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)"

Comment: @joan, thanks for the suggestion same issue

Comment: Hi @Milliways care to elaborate?